# PHP - Global, Update-Able Variable Available to All Clients

Tags: php

GOAL: To have a global variable that any php on my website can access. The variable would be a bool.

What I am stuck on is how I can store such a variable that is available to all php scripts, but can also be updated via php.

The variable is a bool that determines whether or not the site loads advertisements based off if a certain criteria was met that day. So, every day I will have a cron job that runs to reset this variable, thus meaning the variable needs to be update-able via php.

The only way I can think of to store it is either via a db table, which seems like overkill just for one little bool, or a json file that I store outside of the public_html directory.

With the json file, I would just perform a get on load with file_get_contents via my "class lib" file that is present on all pages of the site. Then do something similar to update it with the cron job.

NOTE: I do have a php file that is present on ALL of my pages, so including a file on every page is not a problem.

Is there a better way? It would be nice if there was a way I could just set a PHP superglobal or something, but I'm unsure if settings something like $_SERVER['custom-variable'] sticks or if it's just for that session.

Apologies if this is a simple mis-understanding of how PHP superglobals/constants work.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: file\db pick one

Comment: I'm not sure I'm up for doing the research for a proper answer right now, but environment variables come to mind.You might take a look at [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) and [Symfony's dotenv component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html). I've also encountered in my professional experience people using regexes to modify `define(XXX, true)` to `define(XXX, false)` (what you're describing actually sounds like it could be a constant!). It worked well, but I'm not still not sure I'd recommend that practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. Just store it in the database. This is a perfectly reasonable solution.
2. Store it in a file, in whatever format you want. JSON is handy if you want to store anything more complex than a single string or number.
3. Store it in a PHP file which returns a value, e.g.

   ```
   <?php return array("ads_enabled" => true);
   ```

   then `require()` that file -- the `require()` call will return that value. If your server has a PHP opcode cache enabled, this will be faster than loading a normal file, as the contents of the file will be cached.

   Note that the file cannot return `false`, as that's indistinguishable from the `include()` failing.

The following are **not** viable options:

- Storing it in a session. Sessions are per-user, and start out empty.
- Storing it in an in-memory cache, like APCu or Memcache. Caches are not persistent storage; the value may be evicted from the cache.
- Storing it in an environment variable. Environment variables are awkward to update in most server environments.

Answer (score 0):

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

Use that in your Apache vhost definition if you are using Apache and have access to modify it. I think you can do something similar in .htaccess files.

You can use a .env file and a library for reading that file.

If you are using a front controller where all requests pass through a single index.php file then you can set a global variable or constant in there.